# Merging arrays in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I am performing a csv import to database and have trouble adding a loop inside an array that is being inserted into a table.

```
$lines = 0; 
$queries = "";
$linearray = array();
$data = array();
if ($csvcontent) $query = "TRUNCATE TABLE $databasetable;";
@mysql_query($query);
echo "Part list for ".$databasetable." updated.\n</br>";    
foreach(explode($lineseparator,$csvcontent) as $value){
      $lines++;
      $value = trim($value," \t");
      $value = str_replace("\r","",$value);
      $value = str_replace("'","\'",$value);
      $linearray = explode($fieldseparator,$value);
      $linemysql = implode("','",$linearray);
      $first = array_splice($linearray, 0, 2); 


<... Here I need to have a function that takes certain values from a table and creates an array that basically looks like $b variable....>

$b=array("1","2","3","4","5","6");

foreach($linearray as $x){

$b = implode(",", $b); // example 

            $row = $first;
                $row2 = $first;
            $row[] = $x."','$b"; // here it just stays as static which is no good to me. I need it to cycle...    
            $data[] = implode("','",$row);

        }
}

$xx=0;
foreach ($data as $id) {
$xx++;  
echo $xx;

$query="INSERT INTO csv_test3 VALUES ('$id', '-', '-' , '-', '-')";
$init=mysql_query($query);
```

In essence I need help figuring out how to merge the `$b` array into the foreach loop so that it goes from this:

```
array(18) {
  [0]=>
  string(23) "a','z','1','1,2,3,4,5,6"
  [1]=>
  string(23) "a','z','0','1,2,3,4,5,6"
  [2]=>
  string(23) "a','z','1','1,2,3,4,5,6"
  [3]=>
  string(23) "a','z','1','1,2,3,4,5,6"
  [4]=>
  string(23) "a','z','0','1,2,3,4,5,6"
  [5]=>
  string(23) "a','z','0','1,2,3,4,5,6"
  [6]=>
  string(23) "b','y','1','1,2,3,4,5,6"
  [7]=>
  string(23) "b','y','0','1,2,3,4,5,6"
  [8]=>
  string(23) "b','y','0','1,2,3,4,5,6"
  [9]=>
  string(23) "b','y','1','1,2,3,4,5,6"
  [10]=>
  string(23) "b','y','0','1,2,3,4,5,6"
  [11]=>
  string(23) "b','y','0','1,2,3,4,5,6"
  [12]=>
  string(23) "c','x','1','1,2,3,4,5,6"
  [13]=>
  string(23) "c','x','1','1,2,3,4,5,6"
  [14]=>
  string(23) "c','x','1','1,2,3,4,5,6"
  [15]=>
  string(23) "c','x','1','1,2,3,4,5,6"
  [16]=>
  string(23) "c','x','0','1,2,3,4,5,6"
  [17]=>
  string(23) "c','x','0','1,2,3,4,5,6"
}
```

To this:

```
array(18) {
  [0]=>
  string(23) "a','z','1','1"
  [1]=>
  string(23) "a','z','0','2"
  [2]=>
  string(23) "a','z','1','3"
  [3]=>
  string(23) "a','z','1','4"
  [4]=>
  string(23) "a','z','0','5"
  [5]=>
  string(23) "a','z','0','6"
  [6]=>
  string(23) "b','y','1','1"
  [7]=>
  string(23) "b','y','0','2"
  [8]=>
  string(23) "b','y','0','3"
  [9]=>
  string(23) "b','y','1','4"
  [10]=>
  string(23) "b','y','0','5"
  [11]=>
  string(23) "b','y','0','6"
  [12]=>
  string(23) "c','x','1','1"
  [13]=>
  string(23) "c','x','1','2"
  [14]=>
  string(23) "c','x','1','3"
  [15]=>
  string(23) "c','x','1','4"
  [16]=>
  string(23) "c','x','0','5"
  [17]=>
  string(23) "c','x','0','6"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could do this with a bunch of iterators:

```
$linearray = [['a','z',1], ['a','z',0], ['a','b',1], ['a','c',1]];

$a_iter = new ArrayIterator($linearray);

$b_iter = new LimitIterator(new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator(array("1","2","3","4","5","6"))), 0, count($linearray));

$m_iter = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC);
$m_iter->attachIterator($a_iter, 'a');
$m_iter->attachIterator($b_iter, 'b');

foreach ($m_iter as $item) {
        print_r(array_merge($item['a'], array($item['b'])));
}
```

The `MultipleIterator` allows to loop over multiple iterators at the same time:

1. A standard [`ArrayIterator`](http://php.net/arrayiterator) that feeds from `$linearray`
2. An [`InfiniteIterator`](http://php.net/infiniteiterator) that continuously loops over the array of numbers, [limited](http://php.net/limititerator) by the number of items in `$linearray`

Inside the `foreach` you can then "pluck" values from both iterators.